# regular expression in awk

Tags: regex, awk

```
$ cat awkex
  Ross Geller
  Monica Geller
```

In the above file 'awkex' there are two white spaces before the first name. By executing the below awk command will yield the output but

```
$ awk '/^  R/{ print $1 }' < awkex
Ross
```

Is there a way that I can do that without using the regex as `'/^  R/'` like commands or options in awk to avoid the white spaces? or any other regex will give me the output as 'Ross'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the first names that start with `R` with no leading space in the output:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^R/ {print $1}' awkex
Ross
```